# unsigned char giving error: "expression must have a constant value"

Tags: c++

In visual studios, it's giving me an error on both of these lines saying that `encslength` and `inputslength` must have a constant value.

```
unsigned char enc_out[encslength];
unsigned char dec_out[inputslength];
```

However in my code i've already encountered this error before with the following:

```
const int keylength = 256;

/* generate a key with a given length */
unsigned char aes_key[keylength / 8];
```

`unsigned char aes_key` was asking for a constant value so I had to change `int keylength` to `const int keylength`

When I try and do the same with `encslength` and `inputslength` by changing:

```
size_t inputslength = strlen((const char *)aes_input);
size_t encslength = ((inputslength + AES_BLOCK_SIZE) / AES_BLOCK_SIZE) * AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
```

to

```
const size_t inputslength = strlen((const char *)aes_input);
const size_t encslength = ((inputslength + AES_BLOCK_SIZE) / AES_BLOCK_SIZE) * AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
```

It just gives me the error: "expression must have a constant value"

Could somebody please explain what is different between the two encounters of "expression must have a constant value"?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: You must use `new`(C++) or `malloc`(C) to create dynamic arrays.

Comment: Is this C or C++? Answer varies depending on the language...

Comment: @BlueMoon You can give me answer either in C or C++

Comment: @ChrisBeckett The thing is that if you were programming in C, you would not have a problem since C supports variable-length arrays.

Comment: Tagging this both C and C++ makes it much harder to give a sensible answer. (And did you confirm that you get the same errors both ways? Because you didn't tell us which one gave you those errors. Are we supposed to guess?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Sorry about that, It's C++. I've removed the C tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are calling functions at run-time to calculate `inputslength` it can't be a compile-time constant, and C++ doesn't support run-time [variable-length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

There are two solutions: Allocate the arrays dynamically using `new[]`, or use `std::vector` instead. I recommend using `std::vector`.

Comment: constexpr can used for varaible length array,if something can be determined. Cosntexpr is C++ 11 feature. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr

Comment: I did it with using doing `unsigned char *enc_out = new unsigned char[encslength];` - Thank you for the help